# Can I change \ref's output?

Tags: cross-referencing, ieeetran

When I use `\ref` to cross reference a `\subsubsection`, I get the output `IV-B4` (at least using the `IEEEtran` document class).
Can I change the output to something like `IV-B.4)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be careful with redefining such things. There are most likely good reasons why the default form is like it is.

You can change the reference text by redefining the `\thesubsubsection` macro.
However, this will also affect the Table-of-Contents and – in normal classes – also the number in the `\section` itself. The `IEEEtran` class does these numbers differently and normally you don'y need a ToC, so you could simply do it like this.

Example:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection})}

\begin{document}
See~\ref{test}

\section{TEST}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsection{test}\label{test}

\end{document}
```

This gives:
`See I-A.1)`

---

To only change the reference text but not the ToC entry or sectioning number using any class you can redefine the reference prefix macro  `\p@subsubsection` macro which is normally empty and added before the `\thesubsubsection` macro when the label is created.
You could define it to hold the correct value and then gobble the `\thesubsubsection` part (actually `\csname thesubsubsection\endcsname`):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection})\expandafter\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

Note that this might conflict with packages which change the reference text as well, like `hyperref` (especially its `\autoref` macro).