# Is it possible to change the appearance of a \ref ?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, punctuation

I am using article class, and by default, the numbers of the sections, subsections appear like `1 section, 2 section` in time I want them to appear like `1. section, 2. section` (with dots).

I have redefined the format of my section, subsection, etc. as follows:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
```

because I wanted `.` after the number of the section and the subsection. Fortunately, I got the format that I want, but now I have another problem, when I use the cross-reference to the section or the subsection, I got extra `.` after the reference, like: `as we have seen in section 1..`, or `section 2..` it is unwanted. How can I get rid of this extra `.`? Is there anyway to change or redefine the appearance of the `\ref`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer to [can i change refs output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16670/4301) can be adjusted for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection\arabic{subsubsection}.}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\arabic{section}\expandafter\@gobble}
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}\expandafter\@gobble}
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesubsection\arabic{subsubsection}\expandafter\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{test}\label{test}
\subsection{subtest}\label{subtest}
\subsubsection{subsubtest}\label{subsubtest}


See section~\ref{test} and subsection~\ref{subtest} and subsubsection~\ref{subsubtest}!

\end{document}
```

Note that this is a little bit of a hack.

You could also adjust the sectioning commands using `titlesec` instead.

Comment: This is not the correct way to do that simple thing. It's true that **titlesec** can be used, but the formatting of the (sub)section number is under the control of `\@seccntformat`.

Comment: @egreg: I thought that there should be a better way to do it. Please also see the original question (this is a follow-up) [Can I change \ref's output?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16667/can-i-change-refs-output) and consider answering it as well. Thanks!

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @Mara: actually egreg's solution is better. Give it a try.

Answer (score 8):

See the relevant [UK TUG FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-seccntfmt)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 6):

use the class `scrartcl` instead. It has an optional argument for this:

```
\documentclass[numbers=enddot]{scrartcl}
```